# False Position Method

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, numerical-calculus

Is it possible to use False position method to find the root near $\pi/2$ for [this function](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pgkmfbizwx)?

$$f(x)=\frac12+\frac{x^2}4-x\sin(x)-\frac{\cos(2x)}2$$

As you can see, she is positive so we will never get $f(a) \times f(b)<0$

[image: Graphic]

Comment: Do you mean Regula Falsi Method

Comment: @Moo The regula falsi method is also commonly known as the false position method.

Comment: Thanks @SimplyBeautifulArt!

Comment: @MatheusBarretoAlves: I just ran my implementation of False position and found $x = 1.895961363806696$. Using other numerical routines, they give $x = 1.895494267033981$

Comment: @Moo You may be confusing the (open) secant method with the (closed/bracketing) false position method, which is supposed to bound the root.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: I can provide those too, for $1000$ iterations, we find $x = 1.895572438574731$, with the bound given by $$a = 2, b = 1.895572490680167$$

Comment: @Moo How are you dealing with the requirement that you should have $f(a)f(b)<0$ though? Perhaps you could clarify how you are implementing false position here?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: I am cheating, I am using the algorithm in Numerical Methods by
John H. Mathews and Kurtis Fink, 2004 and the Mathematica implementation of that.

Comment: @Moo I skimmed through the root-finding section but could not find a modified false position algorithm for handling such cases. I'd be interested if you could elaborate (perhaps in an answer).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use a modification of false position for finding minimums of functions to find the root (if it is indeed one).

The idea is that three points $x_\mathrm L<x_\mathrm M<x_\mathrm R$ are given so that $f(x_\mathrm M)<f(x_\mathrm{L~and~R})$.

We then generate a new point $x_\mathrm N$ by applying false position to the points $(x_\mathrm L,\pm f(x_\mathrm L))$ and $(x_\mathrm R,\mp f(x_\mathrm R))$, which will effectively flip the sign of the function on one side of the root.

We then update $(x_\mathrm L,x_\mathrm M,x_\mathrm R)$ so that $f(x_\mathrm M)$ is minimal (between $f(x_\mathrm M)$ and $f(x_\mathrm N)$) and $x_\mathrm L$ and $x_\mathrm R$ are the nearest points found on the left and right sides of $x_\mathrm M$.

See [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ew0wdnoeqg) for a visualization of the process. (There is a slight mistake in the conditions for updating, but the first 3 iterations are still correct.)

See [here](https://tio.run/##VVDLasMwELzvVywCg@QkiuOSHkKc/oDlg6Gn2BSXWMSHKsVWYEvpt7srpU@E0OzMzuyi8fr8Ns8Wi9UBCd8lrfOV6fxZT4OTpFSa5h8Ag@/Hzg8XN2GBmywDoDIgvQUyDHKdAdURbAFer35C4RpPZePDocfbayUZJQDsZUSHg@MA/RsNiNEpRXISuEDR@ERv7q1I7xQmeHRLpJJvvUR7JNO2bKCKh0ou6zbllRZBKRnWCtdf/DepQrt5cj159sQE3Ie3avGBFdxxWuh54cUKZJ1nVa3mMrId/WM7Cmz4hWgY7E/4ITJBraPKxj/qPjJxl6DeWOjdaZ4/AQ) for code.

---

### Update:

I had forgotten that there is a way to get false position to find even order roots. The trick is to force a sign change onto one endpoint and start the other point close to the root but on the opposite side. The convergence of this is extremely slow, however, so I would not recommend doing so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But is possible the use without the modification? Or it will fail the condition?

Comment: A proper implementation of any bracketing method should exit before doing anything if $f(a)f(b)>0$. Otherwise it may fail to converge or converge in an unexpected way (possibly depending on bounds) which is not useful when compared to open methods (such as the secant method).

Comment: I had recalled a way to use false position in this situation, which may be of interest to you. But it should be pointed out that false position converges extremely slowly if you were to do this.